# How to add beans loaded via FileSystemXmlApplicationContext to an existing context loaded via ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, applicationcontext

I have an old application that has all its spring batch beans in class path; these beans get loaded in  application context using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. Now, there is a need where I can put these spring batch beans outside my war/classpath.

If you could please help me here? I can not change existing code and if I load these new definitions using FileSystemXmlApplicationContext, how could I merge them with existing context?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`@ImportResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) in your new application to load the bean definitions from an XML resource:

```java
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:your-old-applicationContext.xml",
        "classpath:another-old-applicationContext.xml"
})
public class NewApplicationConfig {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; but the legacy application has multiple context.xml files; listing them would be another challenge. Is there any way I can merge my new context to existing context?

Comment: If with "existing" you mean "a fully instantiated ApplicationContext", then it's not possible (afaik). Reason is that the ApplicationContext would have to re-instantiate its bean lifecycle to accommodate the newly added beans.

Comment: Yes, with existing I mean a fully instantiated ApplicationContext.